# mailto: in android not supporting link in body with blanks

Tags: android, html, email, mailto

We need to mail links in our HTML5 (mobile)web page, so we used mailto: to provide links for initiating email. The mail content has web page links, and it contains **spaces** 
eg 
[http://maps.google.com/maps?q=chennai Tamil Nadu](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=chennai%20Tamil%20Nadu)

Hence we used URL endcoding so pass the content correctly to the email client.
so the eg link became http://maps.google.com/maps?q=chennai%20Tamil%20Nadu

But the problem is gmail app loads  content after decoding ie with broken links:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=chennai Tamil Nadu

We even tried with double encoding and still it failed. Is there any way prevent this issue in android browsers ??

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the correct parameters such as `?subject` to the protocol? Technically it should work without encoding.

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=http://maps.google.com/maps?q=chennai Tamil Nadu">Mail it</a>
```

Check out [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)